# Webview not working along with animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I am a flutter newbie. I got the code for an animated Flutter login page from GitHub and I was modifying it to suit my requirements. I copied the code for webview from another app I made where it was working, but when I click the button in my new app, nothing happens.

Here is the modified code:

- https://github.com/mansto0/Flutter-Login/blob/master/main.dart

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question instead of providing a link. Links can change and its easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can move `MaterialApp` to `main()`

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()));
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:avatar_glow/avatar_glow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class DelayedAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;

  DelayedAnimation({@required this.child, this.delay});

  @override
  _DelayedAnimationState createState() => _DelayedAnimationState();
}

class _DelayedAnimationState extends State<DelayedAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _controller);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.35), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _controller.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _controller,
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()));
}

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  MyWebView({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: selectedUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final int delayedAmount = 500;
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: 200,
      ),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final color = Colors.white;
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              AvatarGlow(
                endRadius: 90,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                glowColor: Colors.white24,
                repeat: true,
                repeatPauseDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                startDelay: Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: Material(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                      child: FlutterLogo(
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                      radius: 50.0,
                    )),
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: Text(
                  "Hi There",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: color),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 1000,
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: Text(
                  "Welcome to DocSpot",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      color: color),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 2000,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: Text(
                  "Your New Personal",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: color),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 3000,
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: Text(
                  "Healthcare  Companion",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: color),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 3000,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTapDown: _onTapDown,
                  onTapUp: _onTapUp,
                  child: Transform.scale(
                    scale: _scale,
                    child: _animatedButtonUI,
                  ),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 4000,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              DelayedAnimation(
                child: new MaterialButton(
                  height: 60.0,
                  minWidth: 270.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  textColor: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
                  child: new Text("Register"),
                  onPressed: () => {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => MyWebView(
                              title: "DocHelp",
                              selectedUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
                            ))),
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent[300],
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 5000,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        //  Column(
        //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //   children: <Widget>[
        //     Text('Tap on the Below Button',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400],fontSize: 20.0),),
        //     SizedBox(
        //       height: 20.0,
        //     ),
        //      Center(

        //   ),
        //   ],

        // ),

        );
  }

  Widget get _animatedButtonUI => Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 270,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Login',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF1E88E5),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _controller.forward();
  }

  void _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    _controller.reverse();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could you also tell me how you found out this was the problem, in case I run into similar problems in the future, and once again thank you very much.

Comment: I check log and error message. Because you put MaterialApp and Scaffold in the same widget. when you use Navigator. system will  go up one level to find MaterialApp. and system can find. so you need MaterialApp in upper level.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and for being so helpful.